# Assign random name from file to structure name

Tags: c

I'm currently writing a program in C that will end up being a horse race game. The part I'm stuck on is generating random names from a file. I'm using a structure for the horse and a linked list to store 10 horses. The names are in a file "Names". I want to pick a random line in the file, go to it, copy the name to the current node in the linked list, and move on to the next horse. Currently it just stops responding when I start it and returns -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I'm not very experienced with using C to interact with files so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
struct node{
    int data;
    float mult;
    float payout;
    int score;
    struct node *next;
    char name[20];//Where I'm trying to store the random name.
};


void rand_name(node* head, int i){
    //A function to generate a random name from a list of 3162 names.

    FILE* infile;
    infile = fopen("Names","r");

    if(infile == NULL){
        printf("Error opening Names.txt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int cnt, j = rand() % 3162;//Pick a random line to copy.
    char buff[100];

    node *tmp = NULL;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp = head;

    for(cnt = 0; cnt < 1; cnt++){
        tmp = tmp->next; //Get to the current node.
    }
    cnt = 0;
    while(cnt < j){
        //Copy each line until you get to the random line to copy.
        fgets(buff, 100, infile);
        j++;
    }

    strcpy(tmp->name, buff); //Store the last copied line into the node.

    return;
}
```

Comment: `j++;` --> `cnt++`, `tmp = malloc(sizeof(node)); tmp = head;` : `tmp` overwrite by `head`.

Comment: Do you know that there are 3162 lines in the file?  How do you know that?  What if the file was edited?  What should the code do if there aren't that many lines in the file?

Comment: stops responding presumably because it is busy overflowing that `j`, and then it reads past the end of file with fgets; fgets returns NULL...

Comment: remember to `fclose` your file before you return...

Comment: Which compiler are you using? And were you able to compile it?

Comment: I totally missed that j++ error. Thank you!

Comment: It's just for a school project and I made the file so it can't be edited in the program but I'll add error checking for that. I'll also add fclose and stop the j overflow.

Comment: I'm using CodeBlocks with MinGW to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `struct` keyword along with the name of your structure.
ie, use `struct node` instead of just `node` in your program.

Consider using `srand()` along with `rand()` otherwise everytime you run the program, `rand()` will probably return the same value.

When you do `strcpy(tmp->name, buff);` after using `fgets()` to read into `buff`, remember that `fgets()` will keep the newline
(`\n`) at the end of the string. You might want to remove that.

If you are trying to open the file named `Names.txt`, you should write `fopen("Names.txt","r");` instead of `fopen("Names","r");`

[BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) pointed out that in

```
tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
tmp = head;
```

you are first allocating memory to `tmp` and then orphaning that memory by overwriting `tmp` with `head`.
Use another variable to store the new node.

I think you just want to assign a value to `name` of `head`. If so, there's no need to create a new node.

And as [Felix Guo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1834967/felix-guo) pointed out, use `fclose()` to close your file stream when you are done working with it.

EDIT:
Of course, you'll need to change the `j++` in the `while` loop to `cnt++` but you already noticed that.